# ORDER BY and ROW_NUMBER() priority - DB2 and PostgreSQL returning different results, same query

Tags: postgresql, db2, sql-order-by, row-number

I'm trying to understand why DB2 does what I expect here but Postgres does not.

I've managed to replicate the behavior I'm looking at in this rather simple self-contained query.

```
with mytables(id,animal) as (
                 values (1,'Cat'),(2,'Dog'),(3,'Mouse') 
)
select *,
       case 
         when animal = 'Dog' then 0
         when animal = 'Cat' then 1
         else 2
       end my_order_by,
       row_number() over() as rank 
from mytables  
order by my_order_by ;
```

DB2 will return what I expected to see:

```
ID  Animal  MY_ORDER_BY RANK
2   Dog     0           1
1   Cat     1           2
3   Mouse   2           3
```

Postgres returns:

```
ID  Animal  MY_ORDER_BY RANK
2   Dog     0           2
1   Cat     1           1
3   Mouse   2           3
```

It appears to me that Postgres is doing the row_number based on ID rather than what `order by` should have forced.   Is there a way to fix this so that Postgres will do what is expected here?

Using PostgreSQL 13 on Google CloudSQL and DB2 v11 , btw.

Comment: You have no `order by` in your `over()` clause so the database is free to choose any ordering it likes.

Answer (score 1):

Add tje order to the row_number, to get your wanted sorting.

> ```
> with mytables(id,animal) as (
>                  values (1,'Cat'),(2,'Dog'),(3,'Mouse') 
>                  )
>                  select *,
>                         case 
>                           when animal = 'Dog' then 0
>                           when animal = 'Cat' then 1
>                           else 2
>                         end my_order_by,
>                         row_number() over(ORDER BY case 
>                           when animal = 'Dog' then 0
>                           when animal = 'Cat' then 1
>                           else 2
>                         end) as rank from mytables  order by my_order_by ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | animal | my_order_by | rank
> -: | :----- | ----------: | ---:
>  2 | Dog    |           0 |    1
>  1 | Cat    |           1 |    2
>  3 | Mouse  |           2 |    3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fb9601ff9231124f121c2facdfd5a308)*

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you.   Seems pretty verbose though.   Is there a particular reason that Postgres does this differently from DB2?

Comment: Also, looks to me like the original `ORDER BY` is unnecessary once it is moved to the OVER().

Comment: @user2454234 because Postgres isn't Db2?  Honestly different platforms or versions of Db2 might do it differently.  For that matter your version might do it differently with different data.   Without telling the DB what order you want the rows numbered, you are it it's mercy.

Comment: yes the order by outside the window function is unnecessary

Comment: @nbk I don't know of any DB documentation that says the final order by is unnecessary.  It might seem so, but again without it...you're at the DB's mercy.  Adding it shouldn't hurt if the DB already has the data in the right order.

Comment: no window functionaere designed that way, i had a member who had an window function with and without order by and got different results and it is actually written in the fine print of window function, how they affect the select, but as you noticed everybody makes his own rules, but usually they are documented

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, ROW_NUMBER() ordering is controlled by it's own ORDER BY clause
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ... [PARTITION BY ...])`

A more concise way to handle this than nbk's answer would be

```
with mytables(id,animal) as (
                 values (1,'Cat'),(2,'Dog'),(3,'Mouse') 
)
, add_my_order as (
select mytables.*,
       case 
         when animal = 'Dog' then 0
         when animal = 'Cat' then 1
         else 2
       end my_order_by
from mytables  
)
select add_my_order.*,
       row_number() over(my_order_by) as rank,
from add_my_order          
order by my_order_by;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to write the same query than Charles and nbk, with case as a lateral subquery

```
with mytables(id,animal) as (
                 values (1,'Cat'),(2,'Dog'),(3,'Mouse') 
)
select mytables.*,
       my_order_by,
       row_number() over (order by my_order_by) as rank
from mytables
  cross join lateral (values (case 
         when animal = 'Dog' then 0
         when animal = 'Cat' then 1
         else 2
       end)) ob (my_order_by)
order by my_order_by;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&rdbms2=postgres_13&fiddle=f8135cd73ce527ef6cbc80006ca2c5f6)